# Java - Hacer referencia a una clase para sacar el get de un atributo

Tags: java, get, class

tengo un problema con mi código y es que tengo varias clases. Una clase Abstracta llamada Cliente, y otra clase que hereda de esta llamada Agricultor. Bien, pues en el siguiente código quiero sacar un get de un atributo de Agricultor pero aparece "Location: class Cliente" y no sé la manera para que utilice la clase Agricultor.

```
if (clientes[posicionCliente].getClass() == Agricultor.class) {
                tf_credDisponible.setVisible(false);
                tf_formaPago.setVisible(false);
                lb_formaPago.setVisible(false);
                lb_credDisponible.setVisible(false);
                tf_cultivo.setVisible(false);
                tf_numInver.setVisible(true);
                tf_comRegantes.setVisible(true);
                lb_cultivo.setVisible(true);
                lb_numInver.setVisible(true);
                lb_comRegantes.setVisible(true);
                tf_cultivo.setText(clientes[posicionCliente].getCultivo());
                tf_numInver.setText("" + clientes[posicionCliente].getNumeroInvernaderos());


            }
```

En la clase Cliente no hay ningún get y pide que cree los getCultivo y getNumeroInvernaderos para usarlos, pero ya los tengo en la clase Agricultor y son los que quiero utilizar.

También he probado a poner "clientes[posicionCliente].Agricultor.getCultivo();" pero me aparece igualmente "Cannot find symbol" y me pide que cree la clase agricultor en la clase Cliente.

Lo único que necesito es saber como coger los get de esa clase sin poner los atributos estáticos, ya que no estoy utilizando ningún método ni clase estática pero aún así me dice que no se puede referenciar un atributo no estático con un contexto estático .

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Importaste la clase Agricultor en donde la estas usando?, por cierto no uses == para comparar clases, usa el metodo equals(), algo como clientes[pocisionCliente].getClass().equals(Agricultor.class).

Comment: Si no estoy mal, creo que como es una clase abstracta no se puede instanciar, y como no se puede instanciar tienes dos opciones, o hacer private los datos que necesitas obtener y los getters hacerlos estaticos o hacer public los datos que deseas obtener y a la vez que sean estaticos, y no tener entonces los getters, o tal vez simplemente estoy pensando mas allá de la cuenta y simplemente fue que te falto llamar a super en el constructor, aunque no se si esto de un error... nunca uso abstract en java, no sabria decirte.

Comment: Si está importada la clase Agricultor y gracias por la recomendación de comparar clases. He probado a hacer estático el getter y me dice que no se puede referenciar una variable no estática con un método estático, también a hacer los atributos públicos pero me dice lo mismo de estático, y lo que no comprendo es porqué dice lo de estático si en donde estoy utilizando el método no hay nada que sea estático... Y no, están todos los atributos bien llamados con super, pero nada...También si pongo los atributos static tengo un problema porque utilizo un array y no se guarda la info individualmente.

Comment: Un atributo que no sea estático, no lo podrás usar en un método estático porque el método necesitaría una referencia del objeto a donde esté dicho atributo.

Comment: El problema está en que no estoy utilizando ese atributo en un método estático y aún así me lo pide

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede sonar extraño pero talvez te funcione, intenta en la clase Cliente que es abstracta, colocar un constructor y llamar a super:

```
public abstract class Cliente{

     public Cliente(){
         super();
     }

}
```

Comment: http://javadesde0.com/clases-abstractas/ problema encontrado, "Si heredamos de una clase abstracta con extends es obligatorio heredar sus metodos".

Comment: He probado ha poner el constructor y llamar al super y sigue igual con el problema de que una cosa es estática y otra no, teniendo en cuenta que ninguna lo es. A que te refieres con heredar sus métodos? Yo tengo unos métodos en Cliente de getter y setters y tiene un constructor con varios parámetros, pero los cultivos y numero de invernaderos que son atributos solo los tiene la clase Agricultor, con sus respectivos getters y setters. Tengo array de tipo Cliente, y al ser abstracta tengo que utilizar para instanciar la clase Agricultor o Distribuidor que heredan de esta, muchas gracias igual ^^